# Search for rows that have more than half of identical words to each other

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find which rows have identical words more than half of its length.
Here, from the screenshot below you can see that row number 93188 and row number 93248's titles are identical (at least from what we can see from the screen) also 93240 and 93247 are identical.
I would like find all the rows that have identical titled papers so that I can drop one of them and left with only one paper.

`str.contain` needs specific word as a string parameter, so I thought this is not what I can use. Please let me know how can I do this.

[image: einstein dataframe]

Comment: Why only half of the length of the string?

Comment: @SwaggaTing Because einstein dataframe is a subset of much bigger dataframe so if I run on full length thought it would take more time.

Comment: You could consider use the difflib module (standard model of CPython). You could create a new column using the difflib.get_close_matches function. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html. Fit the cutoff argument for your needs.